# Detecting the reason for EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK

Tags: visual-c++, intel, sse, x87

I have a compliacted C and C++ code with heavy mathematics calculations. I use intel C++ - the latest update to compile. I use optimizatons and the application does not give the expected answer. After a long time I managed to reduce the problem to getting EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK
0xc0000092. If I compile without optimization - The program work as expected.

It's a single threaded code on Winxp64 (the application is 32-bit).

MSVC 2010 gives the same results with Debug or Release builds. (I mean Good=Expected results)

Can someone help me where to look? Currently I suspect a compiler bug - since I have no asmsembly code of my own, Only compiler-generated code. I looked at the assembler and it's SSE/x87 mixed code.

I'm looking for directions to look for. Since I'm on trial version (of the intel compiler) I don't have much time for investigations.

I will try to use /Qfp-stack-check tommorow to see if i can find something wrong with my code.

*** Update  ***
I just found a bug in intel compiler. A function returns a value on st(0) but the calling function does not remove it. That way i get the stack exception. Workaround is to use the returned value even that i dont always need it. I will try to reproduce it with code that I can share.

After this workaround intel was faster 35% then msvc2010 on the same code. - That's the main result.

mordy

Comment: Post the code centering around the IP where the `EXCEPTION_FLT_STACK_CHECK` occurred.

Comment: I'm not sure I will be able to do it. I'm just looking for directions and probable causes.

Comment: Are you using borland c++ builder by chance? if so, http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6563244

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it, so this question doesn't show up as unanswered.  That's better than editing the solution into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Update * I just found a bug in intel compiler. A function returns a value on st(0) but the calling function does not remove it. That way i get the stack exception. Workaround is to use the returned value even that i dont always need it.